# DropDownStyle set to DropDownList looks disabled but isn't?

Tags: winforms, combobox

It seems that the Windows 10 style of Combobox looks disabled when I change it's `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList`.

[image: Win10 ComboBox]

On the left is the Combobox before any user interaction. On the right is when a user clicks on it to open it.

Now, I don't like changing default design to something the user might not expect but to me the default design makes it look disabled and might confuse the user.

I've tried setting the control's `BackColor` to white but there was no change.

I want the behavior of `DropDownList` where the user can only pick from the options available and not write in a new option but the look of `DropDown` (a plain white background).

Comment: Change the `FlatStyle` property and check which style is more desired. Also in the worst case you can set `DrawMode` to be owner draw and draw combobox yourself.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Setting `FlatStyle` to `Flat` gives the control a reasonable design. If you submit it as an answer, I'll gladly mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the [`FlatStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.flatstyle(v=vs.110).aspx) property and check which style is more desired.

It seems the `Flat` style is the style you are looking for. (based on your comment)

- **Flat**: The control appears flat.
- **Popup**: A control appears flat until the mouse pointer moves over it, at which point it appears three-dimensional.
- **Standard**: The control appears three-dimensional.
- **System**: The appearance of the control is determined by the user's operating system.

Also in the worst case you can set `DrawMode` to be owner draw and draw combo box yourself using `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` events.